# Losing sync with state in TFC (local execution) when clearing terragrunt cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt, terraform-cloud

I have an AWS ou/account/infra deployment automation pipeline I am working on that uses terragrunt, terraform, and terraform cloud to deploy accounts to an AWS org. I am using `local` execution in TF Cloud, so I run it locally on my machine at this time, and only the state is stored in TFC (as opposed to S3 or GCS). Terragrunt is compatible with this state storage technique but I found that if I `apply` the resources (works great) and then clean the `.terragrunt-cache` (`find . -type d -name ".terragrunt-cache" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;` ) and then `plan` or `apply` the resources that were previously created, I lose sync with the remote state, and it wants to recreate everything. When I replan, the `backend.tf` file is regenerated by Terragrunt in `.terragrunt-cache`, and I'm wondering if the provider is getting a new ID that doesn't sync with the previous provider in the other state. One hack I'm going to try is using aliases. According to the terragrunt docs, this should not be an issue as the state persists and the cache can be lost and regenerated.

Any ideas as to what my issue might be? I am new to Terragrunt and am doing some initial investigation now.

My design is based on the `infrastructure-live` example (and corresponding modules linked in the README). It is shared by Terragrunt here: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example

I am running `terragrunt plan-all -refresh=true` from this directory structure:

```
teamname
├── Makefile
├── base
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── deploy.hcl
├── dev
│   ├── account
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   ├── env.hcl
│   ├── iam
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   ├── regions
│   │   ├── us-east-1
│   │   │   ├── region.hcl
│   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   └── us-west-2
│   │       ├── region.hcl
│   │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
└── terragrunt.hcl
```

I generate a state for the account (in `account/`), and for the infra in the root account (`base/`). All the Terraform modules are in a separate repo.

Comment: Update: It looks like the TFC State is actually not containing my full state, and most of the state only exists locally, so when I clear my cache, I lose all the tfstate files for the resources I've created. Not sure if this is an issue with my terragrunt file structure or terragrunt's integration with TFC.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you reviewed the material in this guide? 

https://gruntwork.io/guides/foundations/how-to-use-gruntwork-infrastructure-as-code-library#integration_with_tfc_tfe